# Display a 'div' box only when a specific checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next form in a Wordpress plugin and I want to display the 'div' box with the 'Price' text field only when the checkboxes 'Not free 1' or 'Not free 2' are checked. I know that this can be achieved with jQuery/javascript, but I am not able to do this myself. Any suggestions?

```
<form action="" method="post" class="adverts-form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="adverts-field-select ">
            <label for="advert_category">Categories</label>
            <div class="adverts-multiselect-options">
                <label class="adverts-option-depth-0" for="advert_category-0">
                    <input name="advert_category[]" value="1" id="advert_category-0" type="checkbox"> Free</label>
                <br>
                <label class="adverts-option-depth-0" for="advert_category-1">
                    <input name="advert_category[]" value="2" id="advert_category-1" type="checkbox"> Not free 1</label>
                <br>
                <label class="adverts-option-depth-0" for="advert_category-2">
                    <input name="advert_category[]" value="3" id="advert_category-2" type="checkbox"> Not free 2</label>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="adverts-field-text" style="display: none;">
            <label for="adverts_price">Price</label>
            <input name="adverts_price" id="adverts_price" type="text">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I tried, without success.

I added in a plugin (*display-price.php*):

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'display-price', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
        WP_PLUGIN_DIR . '/display-price.js', // this is the location of your script file
        array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
    );
}
```

and the *display-price.js*:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var advertNodes = $('#advert_category-1, #advert_category-2 ');
var advertInput = $('.adverts-field-text');

advertNodes.click(function() {
  if (!advertNodes.is(':checked')) {
    advertInput.hide();
  }
  else {
    advertInput.show(); 
  }
});

})
```

Files *display-price.php* and *display-price.js* are in the same directory (the default Wordpress plugins directory).

Comment: see doc for [jQuery.click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [jQuery.toggle](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: @andrew I updated the question.

Comment: Do you get any error messages you could share? What happens?

Comment: No errors, no other events.

Comment: Put an alert before the jQuery(document) line, and one inside that function, and see if you get none, one or two of them. It's debugging time...

Comment: No output from alerts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have arrived to this working solution:

```
// a form in a plugin (not mine):
<form action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <label for="category">Categories</label>
            <select id="category" name="category">
               <option value="">Select Options ...</option>
               <option value="2">Free</option>
               <option value="4">Not free 1</option>
               <option value="7">Not free 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div>
           <label for="price">Price</label>
           <input name="price" id="price" type="text">
        </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>

// another plugin (*display-price.php*) (this is mine)
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
function add_my_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'display-price',
        plugins_url( '/display-price.js' , __FILE__ ),
        array('jquery')
    );
}

// a jQuery (*display-price.js*) to display the 'div' box with
// the 'Price' text field only when the option 'Not free 1' or
// 'Not free 2' are selected
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var cat = ["4", "7"]; // option values for which the price field is displayed
    $("#price").parent('div').hide();

    $('#category').change(function(){
        if($.inArray($('#category').val(), cat) > -1) {
            $("#price").parent('div').show(); 
        } else {
            $("#price").parent('div').hide(); 
        } 
    });
});
```

Both *display-price.php* and *display-price.js* files are located in the same directory (the default Wordpress plugins directory).

Answer (score 2):

I think the options should be radio buttons instead of checkboxes. This code will help you get started:

```
var advertNodes = $('#advert_category-1, #advert_category-2 ');
var advertInput = $('.adverts-field-text');

advertNodes.click(function() {
  if (!advertNodes.is(':checked')) {
    advertInput.hide();
  }
  else {
    advertInput.show(); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Good. It would be good to also do the hide/show code upon page load, as some browsers retain the user input on page refresh. Put it in a function, and call it in $() as well.

Comment: @andrew I added an answer, but I still need some help.