# How to make an array of options with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have used the next code block in [a jQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33335042/1354580) to display a specific `div` block only when some menu options are selected. I am not a jQuery expert, but I think that the `$.viewMap` block can be optimized, so there is no need to repeat each time the `$([])` or `$("#price").parent('div')` parts when I want to add more options in that menu. Any suggestions?

```
$.viewMap = {
   '' : $([]),
   '2' : $([]),
   '4' : $("#price").parent('div'),
   '7' : $("#price").parent('div')
};
```

**UPDATE**

I updated my code, as suggested by @epascarello:

```
var x = $([]);
var y = $("#price").parent('div');

$.viewMap = { '' : x, '2' : x, '4' : y, '7' : y };
```

but I would like something like this:

```
var x = $([]);
var y = $("#price").parent('div');

$.viewMap = {'null, 2' : x, '4, 7' : y};
```

Comment: How does a PHP array apply to JavaScript??

Comment: So store a reference to it outside and reference the variable in the array. `var x = $("#price").parent('div');` and `'4' : x, '7' : x`

Comment: FYI, that's an object, not an array.

Comment: LOL, yes it is... :)

Comment: @barmar I would like to change my code to this scenario: if the selected option value is in a list, than do this, if not, do that. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure. `if ($.viewMap[selected]) { // do this } else { // do that }`

Comment: Thanks, but I was not very clear. I want to optimize the $viewMap to something like this: `$.viewMap = {'null, 2' : x, '4, 7' : y};`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I changed all the jQuery code (thanks to [@Yasitha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18572585/1354580)):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var cat = ["4", "7"]; // option values for which a specific div block is displayed
    $("#price").parent('div').hide();

    $('#category').change(function(){
        if($.inArray($('#category').val(), cat) > -1) {
            $("#price").parent('div').show(); 
        } else {
            $("#price").parent('div').hide(); 
        } 
    });
});
```